# Return function int64 C++ to a C# project

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, visual-c++, c#-4.0

i write a dll that is injected on game and return my localplayer and listArrayplayer on server. Ok work fine
code dll project:
C++ code:

```
__int64 RerturnLocalPlayer() {

    __int64 player = GetLocalPlayer_EX();// __Int64 GetLocalPlayer_EX() is a function that return type __int64 value
    return player;
}
```

in main.h:

```
extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport) __int64 RerturnLocalPlayer();
```

}

mt function

```
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) __int64  GetLocalPlayer_EX()
    {
        DWORD64 pClientGameContext = *(DWORD64*)OFFSET_CLIENTGAMECONTEXT;
        if (!(pClientGameContext)) return 0;
        DWORD64 pPlayerManager = *(DWORD64*)(pClientGameContext + 0x68);
        if (!(pPlayerManager)) return 0;

        DWORD64 pObfuscationMgr = *(DWORD64*)OFFSET_ObfuscationMgr;
        if (!(pObfuscationMgr)) return 0;

        DWORD64 LocalPlayerListXorValue = *(DWORD64*)((DWORD64)pPlayerManager + 0xF0);
        DWORD64 LocalPlayerListKey = LocalPlayerListXorValue ^ *(DWORD64 *)(pObfuscationMgr + 0x70);
        hashtable<DWORD64>* table = (hashtable<DWORD64>*)(pObfuscationMgr + 8);
        hashtable_iterator<DWORD64> iterator = { 0 };

        hashtable_find(table, &iterator, LocalPlayerListKey);
        if (iterator.mpNode == table->mpBucketArray[table->mnBucketCount])
            return 0;

        DWORD64 EncryptedPlayerMgr = (DWORD64)iterator.mpNode->mValue.second;
        if (!(EncryptedPlayerMgr)) return 0;

        DWORD MaxPlayerCount = *(DWORD *)(EncryptedPlayerMgr + 0x18);
        if (MaxPlayerCount != 1) return 0;

        return EncryptedPlayerMgr__GetPlayer(EncryptedPlayerMgr, 0);
    }
}
```

C# Code:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("BFClient1.dll", EntryPoint = "RerturnLocalPlayer",
CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern Int64 RerturnLocalPlayer();                    
Int64 localp = NativeMemory.Read<Int64> (RerturnLocalPlayer());

 Console.WriteLine("LocalPlayer " + localp.ToString("X"));
```

the problem is when i run my c# application my console open and after 3 seconds close and sometimes get error: **Attempt to read or write to protected memory. Usually, this is an indication that another memory is damaged.

can some one try help me?

Comment: NativeMemory.Read<Int64> interprets the return value of your function as **pointer** to an int64 value and reads the value it points to. If this really the case?

Comment: Note that if your native library is compiled as x86 (32-bit) code, you might have a mismatching calling convention (your P/Invoke declares `stdcall` calling convention, but your compiled C++ function exports quite possibly use `cdecl` calling convention.) Suggested recommendation to fix/avoid such situations: state the calling convention for your exported C/C++ functions **explicitly** in main.h, and then use the same calling convention in your P/Invoke declaration.

Comment: Klaus Gütter yes is a function to read int64, but i dont need this function.

Answer (score 0):

`__int64 RerturnLocalPlayer()` is a function that returns a 64-bit value through some calling convention. You seem to think it's `stdcall`, I think you're wrong. However I don't have your source code so you can bang your head against that wall on your own.

`public static extern Int64 RerturnLocalPlayer();` is the right definition (again, calling convention aside, there's no 64-bit register on the 32-bit CPU, so it won't be `stdcall`).

However, `Int64 localp = NativeMemory.Read<Int64> (RerturnLocalPlayer());` is just plain bonkers. You're already getting your integer straight from the marshaller as a return value, use it as such! This would be the correct way of calling your function:

```
Int64 localp = RerturnLocalPlayer();
```

Comment: @CerraossoUC, ok and? Is it still a problem? Have you tried my suggestion? I still see the same native memory read call in your updated code.

Comment: yes, i forget to remove nativememory from description, but i tried Int64 localp = RerturnLocalPlayer(); but have same problem nothing happend and close my app. and yes, i change from StdCall) to CallingConvention.Cdecl). =/